# How Does An Interpreter Work?

Tags: programming-languages, interpreters

I've been searching for tons of websites for how an interpreter works, but I found none of these explain how Interpreter works internally. But I found in many places how compiler works with all the steps and descriptions.

So my question is, how does an Interpreter work?

Comment: Shortest explanation possible: Most of them compile the sourcecode to a bytecode somewhat similar to assembly and execute the instructions one by one.

Comment: Your question in the current form is IMHO very broad, maybe too for the Q&A format of this site. Why not start at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)), and when you come to a point you need a more detailed exaplanation, ask a more specific question?

Comment: An interpreter does exactly the same things as a compiler (lexing, parsing, semantic analysis, type inference, type checking, implicit conversions, overload resolution, name resolution, optimization, etc.) *except* the *very last step*, where a compiler *outputs* code corresponding to the semantics of the program, an interpreter *runs* code corresponding to the semantics of the program.

Answer (score 11):

Your question is too broad to be answered in a few paragraphs. And actually interpreters do not mean much: the BASIC interpreter of the [ZX80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80) (in 1980) is really different from today's [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile), [Lua](http://lua.org), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org), or [Python](http://python.org/) interpreters on most Linux systems. Knowing several programming languages, e.g. by reading Scott's [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/), is worthwhile.

[Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) like languages like [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) (& Common Lisp) are [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), and it is very easy to write a small Lisp interpreter in Lisp. The famous [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) book (freely available introduction to programming, using Scheme) has its [chapter 4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-25.html#%25_chap_4) dedicated to such a [meta-circular evaluator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-circular_evaluator).

[Interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) share with [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) several features and tasks; most of them are [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) the code into some [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) like a compiler does. This is actually the easiest part. So a textbook on compilers like the latest edition of the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition) is highly relevant for interpreters.

<sup>(AFAIK, BASIC from the 1980s did not build any AST but parsed repeatedly each line; this is why ZX80's BASIC is not like current interpreters; but I might be wrong, since these old interpreters are proprietary software)</sup>

Some interpreters are evaluating the AST in some environment thru a naive recursive function. Others (and today, many of them), are actually *compiling* the AST into a more efficient form, often some kind of [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) (which gets later interpreted by a fast [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), often stack based and with [threaded code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code)). Some implementations are even using [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques to dynamically produce machine code (so in fact, the frontier between interpreters and compiler is quite fuzzy; notice that [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) is translating to machine code every interaction of its [Read Eval Print Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop); you could perceive it as a "compiler" disguised as an "interpreter" or vice versa).

[Garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) is highly relevant for interpreters. You may want to read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

An excellent book about interpretation and compilation of Lisp like dialects is Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html). It explains in detail various implementations of Lisp (from naive interpreters to sophisticated compilers to C code).

You'll find many free software interpreters to study, and several tutorials on making one, e.g. Norvig's [(How to Write a (Lisp) Interpreter (in Python))](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) and many others.

Notice that designing and implementing a robust, efficient & user-friendly interpreter is a lot of work (you could spend several years on this). If you have some software to which you want to add some interpreter, consider instead **embedding** an *existing* interpreter like  [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) or [Lua](http://lua.org) (both are designed to be easily embeddable).

Comment: The BASIC interpreter sold by Microsoft for pre-CP/M computers stored the program in a tokenised form, so that keywords such as FOR and LET were one byte each (they used ASCII, so the "top bit = 1" bytes were available for this). Given this format, they interpreted each line every time it was executed. I know, because I disassembled one.

Answer (score 2):

An interpreter is feed a program represented as a data structure, then it steps through each of the tasks in the data structure and performs the tasks as it goes. The data structure can be a abstract syntax tree of the code you wish to interpret, or it can even be a byte-code if you wish.

Interpreters may also hold on to a table (hash map) of variable names -> values of variables currently in scope. But not strictly necessary.

An interpreter can be thought of as a pretend CPU that you've created with code.

Comment: … and a real CPU is nothing but an interpreter for its instruction set.

Answer (score -3):

I can tell you that by personal experience, because at our school, we had to create our own language, own compiler and own interpreter.

I suppose you know, what the language and compiler is, so I will skip that. The compiler will create some structure from source code, that is executable by interpreter. It is up to you, how the structure looks like and how the compiler executes it.

The common one is "bytecode", where there is no difference between "data" and "commands" if you do not know the syntax, but you read them from "left to right" and executes it. The interpreter is for example Java Virtual Machine - it gets the .jar, which is executable for that interpret and it executes it.

How that can look like? For example we defined that "1" is command for adding and it takes next byte and add it to the stack. And "2" is for output without requiring any parameters.

```
1511132217
```

If byte is not parameter, it is command. Which means

```
15 - one is command to take next param and add it, it adds 5 (consider uninitalized command to have 0 at stack)

11 - take one and add 1 = 6

13 - Add 3 = 9

2 - output 9

2 - output 9

17 - add 7 = 16
```